# Very simple Objective-C HTTP GET request code cannot compile

Tags: objective-c, gcc, command-line, compiler-errors

I need some help with compile errors. The whole program is below:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    NSLog("entered main\n");
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://YourURL.com/FakeURL/PARAMETERS"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
    }] resume];
    NSLog("leaving main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It's my second day programming in Objective-C. All I'm trying to do it to make a GET reqeust from Objective-C. This is on OSX with gcc. I have xcode installed but this is such a simpe program. The compiler complains:

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSLog", referenced from:
      ___23-[Easyhttp sendHTTPGet]_block_invoke in Easyhttp-c1cd8d.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOperationQueue", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Easyhttp-c1cd8d.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Easyhttp-c1cd8d.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURL", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Easyhttp-c1cd8d.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Easyhttp-c1cd8d.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSessionConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Easyhttp-c1cd8d.o
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in Easyhttp-c1cd8d.o
      CFString in Easyhttp-c1cd8d.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You do not link against foundation. Please add the compile command to your Q.

Answer (score 0):

Those classes you are using are a part of the Foundation framework  (NSString, NSLog, etc.). You will need to import it into your code.

Comment: It is not the import, but the link.